# Add react project as dependency in angular project package.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, migration

I have an existing angular project and I’m creating a new react project and I have to add this react project as Npm dependency in my existing angular project (package.json)
This is as part of migration of angular to react

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a npm package for your code and then deploy it over npm for this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).